# Fluid Simulation with Forces Blender 2.9. How do I get useful results?

Tags: fluid-simulation, force-fields

This is about the built in Fluid Simulation with Blender 2.9

Yes I do see the effect of the gravity force and [force[shape curve]].

Will other forces work with Blender?   Such as Harmonic?

When I try to use other forces I get undesired

- Explosion Splashes Messes
- Splatters Droplets which seem to pass through obstacles
- Increased Liquid (Visual Inspection with doubt.  I am not sure if Blender provides that measurement)

At the moment, I am seeking visual results not scientific results.

Is there some typical action I must take to get more flowing results?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not.

Blender is for SFX. Stuff that's good enough to fool the human eye, but not precise enough for simulations that give scientific results.

- Explosions can be due to obstacles that aren't solid enough. Make them really thick, thick enough to go out through the domain, if you can.
- Droplets going through stuff might be fixed by increasing the particle size and/or increasing the time steps (so that the simulation can detect the collision even if the droplet is travelling very fast)

I don't know what to do about the last one, it just happens and you have to compensate for it.

You'll probably just have to forget about precision. For visualization and proof of concept it's probably fine (even if you have to tweak it and cheat here and there), but there's no true precision.